# How to hide website files from 3rd party system administrators?

Tags: linux

Is it possible to block or hide files to third party system administrators? I need a 3rd party (service) to optimize my web server and database for me. But I don't want them copy or see my application files. What is the right way to get this service?
Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps somebody else has an actual answer to your question, but I’d like to point out that it’s relatively common to have written contracts with consultants and/or their parent companies. It doesn’t
prevent them from possibly prying - it’s not uncommon that they need admin/root rights to certain systems - but it allows you to create a case against them if they use your intellectual property for anything unrelated to your own systems.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you want to do, bit the short answer is, in the general case, this can't be done.

(I am aware of some edge cases in cryptography where its possible for work to be done on encrypted sets of data so the party doing it does not see the raw data but its highly experimental and not applicable here).

About the best you can do is find an provider you can work with who can guide you through the steps of optimising yourself - many providers will have scripts they can run that can examine (for example) the database and provide an output with advice on what and how to optimise without your data being seen. (You do need to trust the scripts you are given to run though).

I believe there are similar scripts for many aspects of tuning.

FWIW, even financial institutions trust third parties to handle their data/keys just using contractual arrangements - this is not uncommon.